# DevExpress.XtraScheduler does not work after 1 week

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Please help me find out what is going on with DevExpress.XtraScheduler control.

Here are some steps I used to run recurrence schedule:
1. Set up schedule:

```
        Appointment apt;
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        apt.BeginUpdate();

        apt.Subject = "weekly";
        apt.Start = startTime;
        apt.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        apt.StatusId = 2;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.AllDay = false;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.Type = RecurrenceType.Weekly;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.Start = startTime;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.Range = RecurrenceRange.NoEndDate;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.OccurrenceCount = 100;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.DayNumber = 0;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.Periodicity = 1;
        apt.RecurrenceInfo.WeekDays = WeekDays.Monday;
        apt.HasReminder = true;
        apt.Reminder.TimeBeforeStart = TimeSpan.Zero;

        apt.EndUpdate();
```

1. It worked correct in the first week, but it did not fire an event in the next week. I don't know why it is? could you please give me some clues to I can fix them? or because I used the old version (1.1)?
2. With the set up schedule as above, is it correct?

Please advices. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised to see you assign `1` to `RecurrenceInfo.DayNumber`.  At best, this would be ignored with a weekly recurrence.  At worst, this would require that your Monday be the first day of the month.  Assign `0` or don't assign this property at all.

Comment: yeah, thank you so much for helping me. I'll change and monitor this.